# How to Add Amazon Affliate Banner in vue app

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to add the Amazon affliate banner to a component in my vue web application.

Below is the Amazon code.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var aax_size='160x600';
    var aax_pubname = 'samplename';
    var aax_src='***';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://c.amazon-adsystem.com/aax2/assoc.js"></script>
```

However adding this in the index.html wasn't giving expected results.
I want this to add to a vue component. The below code doesn't even show the banner.

**mycomponent.vue**

```vue
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- Some contents -->
    </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var aax_size='160x600';
    var aax_pubname = 'samplename';
    var aax_src='***';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://c.amazon-adsystem.com/aax2/assoc.js"></script>
<script>
    export default {
        // Vue options api code
    }
</script>
```